# How to create Scala trait which stores data from other columns in dataset and then create new dataset with column storing the trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-spark

I am new to Scala and am currently studying datasets for Scala and Spark. Based on my input dataset below, I am trying to create a new dataset (see below). In the new dataset, I aim to have a new column which contains a Scala trait `Seq[order_summary]`. The Scala trait stores data the corresponding `Name`, `Ticket Number`, and `Seat Number` taken from the input dataset.

I have implemented `input_dataset.groupyBy("Name")` to organise the dataset and have tried   `df.withColumn("NewColumn", struct(df("a"), df("b")))` to combine different columns together. However, I would like to use a Scala trait instead and am also stuck with matching the name to the ticket number. Would anyone know how to resolve this or point me towards the right direction?

Input dataset: `input_dataset`

Name Type is String. Ticket Number Type is Int

```
+----+---------------+-------------+
|Name| Ticket Number | Seat Number |
+----+---------------+-------------+
|Adam|      123      |     AB      |
|Adam|      456      |     AC      |
|Adam|      789      |     AD      |
|Bob |     1234      |     BA      |
|Bob |     5678      |     BB      |
|Sam |      987      |     CA      |
|Sam |      654      |     CB      |
|Sam |      321      |     CC      |
|Sam |      876      |     CD      |
+----+---------------+-------------+
```

Output dataset

`Name` Type is `String`. `Purchase Order Summary` is a `trait`, `Seq[order_summary]`

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|Name| Purchase Order Summary                              |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|Adam|((Adam,123,AB),(Adam,456,AC),(Adam,789,AD))          | 
|Bob |((Bob,1234,BA),(Bob,5678,BB))                        |
|Sam |((Sam,987,CA),(Sam,654,CB),(Sam,321,CC),(Sam,876,CD))|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: A Scala `trait` is just an interface. They don't store data per se. You're looking for an implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure Spark has a [map](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-map-transformation/) method.

So you could just create a case class

```
case class PurchaseOrderSummary(name: String, ticketNum: Long, seatNum: Int)
```

and instantiate it inside a map from your DF, then collect it into a list.

```
df.map(row => PurchaseOrderSummary(row.getString(0), row.getLong(1), row.getInt(2))).collectAsList
```

collectAsList should retrieve data from the RDD and transform it to a scala List[PurchaseOrderSummary].